# XSLT convert SimpleDateTime to GMT-00:00 timezone

Tags: xslt, timezone, format

I need help on XSLT to reformat time, without much luck.

```
<names> 
    <name>
        <foo id='x_date'>
             <value> 01/23/2011 13:20:00 PDT</value> 
        </foo> 
    </name>
</names>
```

How will I change the date from '**01/23/2011 01:23:00 PDT**' to '**01/23/2011 09:24:00 GMT+00:00**' via XSLT?

Please help, it's killing me :-)

Comment: Does it have to be `XSLT` itself or are you open to vendor-specific `XSLT` extensions (such as Java's Xalan, for instance)

Comment: I can either do this in XML editor, oXygen (with SAX PE) or write a simple java program to do transformation (I had SAX 8.0+), but writing extension is out of reach for me, since I am not an expert in XSLT

Comment: OK, I'll explain more in my answer. Writing extensions with Xalan is quite simple...

Comment: Thank you, I will try that, no more format-dateTime(), replace(), concat() for a while.  It seems not terribly difficult my implementing my own function...

Comment: Nah, when Xalan *is* an option, you will hardly ever want to go back to those rather basic XSL / XPath functions :-)

Comment: Use the XPath 2.0 function `adjust-time-to-timezone()`. Of course, `value` needs to be transformed into a valid xs:dateTime first. I will post an answer when I have more time.

Comment: I tried 3 different ways. I eventually just settle for Java Regex Expressions....  1) Customer date time function with Java, when I do this, it complains don't have the paid Xalan PE version so wont' work.  2) my oXygen editor seems to have Xalan PE, but it doesn't recognize my functions when I create a tranfromation rule.  3) because of previous two tries, I had a custom java formatter object for this task (class MyExtension), I combined the Java Regex & Apache Common and it seems to work without all that...

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to use a non-XSLT solution using Java's Xalan extensions, for instance, you could opt for the date time functions as documented here:

http://exslt.org/date/index.html

Something along the lines of

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  date:format-date(
    date:parse-date(/names/name/foo/value, $inPattern),
    $outPattern)" />
```

In your specific case, you'd probably have to implement your own date formatter in a custom namespace. This is quite simple:

- Add [Xalan](http://xalan.apache.org/) to your classpath
- Create a custom date formatter:

```java
    package org.example;
    public class MyExtension {
      public static String myFormat(String date) {
        // Do the formatting
      }
    }
```

- Use the above formatter in an XSLT stylesheet:

```xml
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:myextension="http://org.example.MyExtension">
      ..
      <xsl:value-of select="myextension:myFormat(/names/name/foo/value)"/>
      ..
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

More documentation can be found here:

http://exslt.org